# CSS - Disable text color change when mouse is over screen area?

Tags: css

- - First, right out the gate: This does not appear to be your usual hover or focus event.  It also does not appear to be a transition or transformation.  I've tried disabling these events to no avail. * *

Issue: When the mouse is over an area of the website highlighted below in blue, the side text (but not the image or the link header above the image) turns from black to slightly gray.  I'm using Joomla and just want to be able to add a bit of CSS into my user.css (where I put override css) to stop this from happening.  I've done this to remediate a ton of other issues and it has worked every time.

[issue areas in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwhlE.jpg)

Here is code for the affected area that I am trying to interact with:

```
                              <div class="com-tags__items">
    <form action="http://sandboxuo.com/" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
            </form>

            <ul class="com-tags-tag__category category list-group">
                                                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                                                    <h3>
                        <a href="/index.php/blog/test-blog-post-5">
                            Test Blog Post 5                        </a>
                    </h3>
                                                                                                    <a href="/index.php/blog/test-blog-post-5">
                        <img src="/images/content/blog5.png" alt="" width="400" height="225" loading="lazy">                    </a>
                                                                                            <span class="tag-body">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. Non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus. Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis.</p>...                    </span>
                                                                            </li>
```

I have tried everything I can think of over the last day to stop the graying from occurring.  Disabling hover events, focus, etc. all fails to work.  The only thing that has worked works too well.  The following will remove the graying effect but also disables the hand icon over link and image and prevents those links from working (obviously):

```
.list-group-item.list-group-item-action {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I have tried to remediate this by going back and setting pointer events to "auto" for certain elements within, like "a" and "img".  This works partially -- the text does not gray when I hover over the text, but hovering over the image or top link grays the text still!

I am at my wits end.  I cannot determine how to switch this off.

Comment: If you want to change the paragraph styles when the list item is hovered, use `.list-group-item:hover p`

Comment: Joseph, I thought that I had already tried this which is the only reason I didn't previously.  One of those examples where I must simply have not saved changes or otherwise passed this over.  It works!  Thank you.